# Not able to run grep command

Tags: java, android, linux, android-mediaplayer, lsof

I was trying to run the following instruction in Android (Java):

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/lsof|grep mediaserver");
```

but I am getting an error if I run the following instruction:

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/lsof ");
```

the file is successfully saved. Can anyone tell what is the error? Actually I want to list and check if media server service is being running or not.

Comment: Well, since you are the one getting the error, perhaps you could tell us what the error is. Maybe then we could help you, no?

Comment: First guess?  Since you have to put /system/bin in front of the lsof command, maybe try putting the path to grep in there too? i.e. use /system/bin/lsof | /system/bin/grep mediaserver" or whatever the path to grep is.

Comment: i am getting the following error W/System.err(345): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/system/bin/lsof|grep, init] Working Directory: null Environment: null

Answer (score 1):

The grep utility may not be installed on your device.

You can check it by trying the following in a console:

```
> adb shell
$ grep
grep: not found
```

The last line indicates that this command is not available.

Comment: What can I do if grep is missing? Are there shell alternatives?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27615220/grep-command-not-found-in-adb-shell

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` does not know how to deal with the shell language.  On a Linux / Unix platform you would so something like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
    "/bin/sh", "-c", "/system/bin/lsof | grep mediaserver"});
```

However, (apparently) Android doesn't have a command shell / command prompt by default.  So either you need to identify and install a suitable shell on your device, or construct the pipeline "by hand"; i.e. by creating a "pipe" file descriptor, and execing the two commands so that `lsof` writes to the pipe and `grep` reads from it.

Maybe the answer is to run it like this ...

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        "adb shell /system/bin/lsof | grep mediaserver");
```

(Try running the "shell ...." part from adb interactively before doing it from Java.)

Comment: thanks for the reply i am getting error W/System.err(1370): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/bin/sh, -c, /system/bin/lsof | grep init] Working Directory: null Environment: null

Comment: what is this string for  "/bin/sh"