# grep command not found in adb shell

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell

After my phone is connected to the computer through adb, going to adb shell and then typing `grep` gives me

```
grep: not found
```

Is this a problem with my adb installation or my phone? How do I get grep to work for my device?

PS: This is the reason why I think it might a problem with my phone (as opposed to the adb installation)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12143669/1693203
The answer says

> The grep utility may not be installed on your device.

However, I may have misunderstood the statement. How do I get grep working?

Comment: You can't run "grep" if there is no `grep` available on the device, this has nothing to do with your adb installation

Comment: is there a way to get it without rooting the phone?

Answer (score 2):

`grep` command is not installed on your device by default. If you need to use `grep` command in your device, you can cross-compile `busybox` then invoke `grep` under `busybox`.

However if you are in `Linux` or `Cygwin`, you can pipe the command output and use the `grep` in PC to get result you want, e.g.

```
$ adb shell ps |grep google
app_5     279   71    200212 30928 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.process.gapps
app_66    481   71    122804 21632 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.apps.maps
app_66    32311 71    120200 20916 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.apps.maps:NetworkLocationService
```

Comment: why crosscompile? simply install from playstore.

Comment: Nowadays, android already support arm, arm-64, mips, x86, x86_64. The reliable way to install binary program is by cross-compiling to the target architecture.

Comment: i nevertheless think it makes it unnecessarily complicated for him.

Answer (score 1):

in your case that means:The grep utility <del>may</del> **is** not be installed on your device.

install busybox from [playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=de) then perform

```
busybox grep
```